# Visual Studio 2017 "Go to All" does not list items

Tags: visual-studio, search, ide, visual-studio-2017

VS 2017's new "Go to All" (Ctrl + T or Ctrl + ,) does not lists items for me.

Searched for a setting for it, no luck. Also no error messages regarding this at all.

Why is this happening, and how can I get the behaviour I expect?

Comment: Does this start with a colon character ':' (goto line)? Because that is my current default and the reason why I am here? You can remove this to search all or press ? for more options. Does somebody know how to change this?

Comment: @Remco did you ever find a solution

Answer (score 239, accepted):

I encountered this issue as well.  Somehow I had collapsed the list.  If you hover over the point in the picture below you should get a resize handle.  Grab it and pull it down to get your list back.

[image]

Comment: This unknowingly happened to me too, I thought it was some new feature from the update, something like "I'm feeling lucky" (like in google search) where it took you to first best result, but then I realized wait this is not right anymore XD.

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue is hotkeys. Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard->Edit.GoToAll

assign shortcut keys (usually CTRL + ,)

Answer (score 1):

For me - helped to **move project folder to another path** and open in visual studio as a new project. You can simply test that scenario by creating new visual studio solution and try to search there - if search will works, then folder movement could be a solution for you.

Just to note - i tried to open nodejs project, there are about more then 300k files and maybe it's the main reason, also maybe it was visual studio cache (tried to delete cache files - it was unhelpful).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by deleting my `.vs` folder and `*.csproj.user` files from my repository (done with git-clean)