# Visual Studio Go to All (ctrl + ,) going to first search result without showing list of results

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Whenever I use Go To on Visual studio 2017 and I start typing something it will just find the first occurrence of whatever I typed and go to that file without showing me a list of Classes / Methods like it used to do before. Right now I don't see any list of possible results and it's making it pretty hard to navigate my code. I have been looking online and couldn't find a solution to this. What can I do to get that list of results to show up?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you are seeing? And do you have Resharper installed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43286088/visual-studio-2017-go-to-all-does-not-list-items This fixed my problem.